# Why is the Lookup component delaying the data flow and how do I find out why?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a data flow to migrate rows from a database to a new version of the database. One of the changes we are making is to replace user name strings with an integer identifier.

I'm using a Lookup component to replace the Manager and Trader names with their numeric ID but one of the transforms seems to be performing very slowly compared to the other. In the following screen shot it shows how far behind the `Lookup Trader` component is compared to the `Lookup Manager` component.

[image: SSIS Data Flow]

As you can see approx 22m rows have been passed to the `Lookup Manager` component and it is "only" 100k row behind but the data passed to the `Lookup Trader` component is almost 8m rows behind.

The lookups contain the same query to get the user name and ID for all the traders and managers (they are maintained in the same table) and are both set to use `Full Cache`. They are looking up the same data type (string) and both add a new field to the flow of type `INT`.

I don't understand why one component is performing so much faster than the other when they are essentially the same. The Warning icons on both components are shown because I have set the error action to `Fail Component` while debugging even though there is an error output connected. Later, I'll redirect the errors to a flat file.

My question is two fold; why is one performing much slower than the other and, more importantly, how do I find out *why*?

Comment: What's the next component after Lookup Trader? If the output buffers are full, I think Lookup Trader would be blocked from producing any more output.

Comment: It's a multi-cast with two outputs. I see what you are thinking, that it is something else down the flow unable to consume the data fast enough?

Comment: only a wild guess though, hence why I've put it as a comment :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comment from Damien_The_Unbeliever about components later in the data flow I did a test by extracting the two lookup components and directing their output a to a [Trash Destination](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Trash-Destination-Adapter.aspx);  I also reversed the order of the components to see if one was operating faster than the other.

All was running well until *both* lookup components paused and the input raced ahead to nearly 5m rows but overall the data was processed quickly and the `Lookup Trader` component did not work more slowly than the `Lookup Manager`.

So it would seem the later components are causing a bottleneck in the flow and therefore making it appear the `Lookup Trader` was the culprit.

[image: Test data flow]

Comment: I'm hoping that means you've found a way to deal with your bottleneck (or accept it :-|)

Comment: Your original comment has certainly made me think more about the performance of the whole data flow and not just one component. So, yes, for the moment I have to accept it (until I have time to re-factor the flow). Thanks again for your suggestion.

Comment: As there have been no further comments or answers I'm marking my own explanation as the accepted answer. Unless you want to post your comment as an answer, Damien, in which case I'll accept that as it did describe in general terms why the flow was not processing rows in a uniform manner.